# jQuery fadeToggle back to default

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table and I'm using `fadeToggle` on the list to hide and show the data but I want to create a "Back to All" function. That is, when I click "Back to All" it will revert all the toggled elements (the ones I have clicked) but I'm not sure to do it.

**HTML**

```
 <div class="main">
            <ul class="top_menu" >
                <li class="orderList" id="starter_li">Starter</li>
                <li class="orderList" id="soup_li"> Soup</li>
                <li class="orderList" id="seafood_li">Seafood</li>
                <li class="orderList" id="return_li">Return All</li>
            </ul>
            <div id="middleBox">
                <table class="food_table" id="starters" style="width:100%">
                    <tr></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>S1</td> 
                        <td>Starter1<br>
                        <td>10</td>
                    </tr>
            <table class="food_table" id="soups" style="width:100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>Soup1</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                    </tr>   
                </table>
             <table class="food_table" id="seafood" style="width:100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>seafood1</td>
                        <td>7</td>
                    </tr>   
                </table>
```

**jQuery**

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#starter_li").click(function(){
        $("#starters").fadeToggle(500);
    });
        $("#soup_li").click(function(){
        $("#soups").fadeToggle(500);
    });
        $("#seafood_li").click(function(){
        $("#seafoods").fadeToggle(500);
      });
        $("#return_li").click(function(){
                $(".food_table").fadeToggle(500);
        });
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.food_table` class as a common selector and then use a jQuery function to show them (e.g. fadeIn() or show())

Example:

```
$('#backToAll').click(function () {
  $('.food_table').fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: YEA! Why i didn't think about that LOL